# Getting all the child records

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Query and below are the tables.

**Organization**

```
OrgID     Name             RAOID      SubGroupID
1         Org RAO1         2          NULL
2         Org RAO2         NULL       2
3         Org Sub Group1   3          NULL
4         Org RAO3         NULL       1
5         Org RAO4         1          NULL
6         Org Sub Group2   NULL       3
```

**RAO**

```
RAOID   RAOGID
1         1
2         1
```

**Sub Group**

```
SubGroupID  RAOID
1            1
2            1
3            1
4            2
```

I have three tables Organisation, RAO, SubGroup. I can have organisations either of type RAO or SubGroup. However if you see the subgroup table it is having multiple RAOID. I want all the subgroup organisation name under rao when any rao orgid is passed to query.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question, specifically with regards to what RAO and SubGroup mean. Seeing related columns isn't enough to help me understand if you're looking for several organizations that are related to be returned from one OrgId, or if something entirely different (missing column?) is going on.

Comment: RAO and SubGroup are type of oraganisations, I mean every time when I create any organisation it will be a RAO or Subgroup. But every subgroup is under some RAO, who's entry is entered in subgroup table. So I want to list all the subgroup organisation name if i pass orgid to the query.

Comment: You want to filter by ORGANIZATION.orgid or RAO.raogid?  It's not clear to me what you mean by "rao orgid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with below query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetSubSource
( @ORGID INT)
AS
DECLARE @RAOID INT
SET @RAOID = (SELECT RAOID FROM tblOrganisation WHERE ORGID = @ORGID)

IF @RAOID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SELECT tblOrganisation.ORGID,
tblOrganisation.NAME as SUBSOURCENAME FROM tblOrganisation 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSubGroup ON tblOrganisation.SubGroupID = tblSubGroup.SubGroupID
WHERE
tblSubGroup.RAOID = @RAOID
END
```

Cheers!!